# How do I render a sqlalchemy column into a html file with flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy, blogs

I am working on a feature for my business website that prints all the titles of blogs on the blog page then takes you to a url consisting of that blogs name. But I recently ran into a brick wall when I couldn't figure out how to print all of the titles into the html page.

Here is the code that I made to test the feature out:(Not done)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "Iknowwhatthesecretkeyis"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///datatbase.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app) 



class Blog(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(50))

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
    if request.method=='POST':
        title = request.form.get("title")
        content = request.form.get("content")
        author = request.form.get("author")
        blog = Blog(title=title, content=content, author=author)
        db.session.add(blog)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('post.html')

@app.route('/posts')
def posts():
    all_titles = Blog.query.filter_by(title='').all()

@app.route('/posts/<title>')
def postsection():
    return "nothing here rn"
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

All I need is a way to put all of the blog titles into the html page. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have found an answer it just took a lot of digging.
For the route:

```
@app.route('/titles')
def postsection():
    posts = Blog.query.all()
    return render_template('titles.html', posts=posts)
```

Then for the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>titles</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for post in posts %}
{{post.title}}<br>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Note: This is using the same model and code from my question just with this added.